# Can I "Force Return" from a void method in the Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

While debugging in Eclipse, it would be useful for me to avoid the side effects of a void function by just doing a force return (which I have done before with a non-void method).

However, the context menu item is always disabled when I try to return from a void method. Specifically, I tried going into the Display pane while debugging, enter a value I'd like to return, right-click and select "Force Return". Obviously, a void method is not supposed to return anything so I can understand why this menu item is disabled.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, or does some feature of Java prohibit me from doing it?

Comment: you can always type 'return' in a void method while programming java, so void methods do have returns.

Comment: You can use `void aMethod() { return; System.out.println("This will be never printed");}`

Comment: He is asking about debugger behavior, not code. Downvoter, you might reconsider your down vote, this is a fair question.

Comment: This question is about Eclipse debugging not about Java itself.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I did not know you could force return a value at all, I learned something.

Comment: Why not just step over the void function instead?

Comment: @ardentsonata Step over would still run the code. What OP wants is to go halfway through a method, then force a return before it actually ends, making the rest of the method not run at all.

Comment: @ardentsonata I'd like specifically to avoid executing the code in the function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, don't use the context menu in the Variable display, but right-click in your code and you will see "Force Return" in the context menu.

Comment: I just saw that, thanks. Another issue for me was that Force Return is only supported in Java 1.6, and I was using Java 1.5. Switched to 1.6 and now it works.

Comment: @therin Another useful thing to know.

Comment: Not only can you return from a void method, but also from a method with no-void return value. Check the official Eclipse document, http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-forcereturn.htm .