# Force the VC++ debugger return from a function

Tags: visual-c++

Very often I have a function that causes an issue but not a crash, so I want to disable code that causes that issue but I don't know exactly what piece of code causes it.

So I have the function return at various points until I find the issue, for example by injecting code like

```
if (1) return;
```

at various places of the function.

The problem with this is that I have to constantly stop and recompile the application.

Is there a runtime VC++ debugger feature that would instruct the debugger to exit the function as If executing a return statement? I could drag the 'next statement to be executed' at the end of the function but this is cumbersome for big functions.

Assembly-wise it's possible by changing RIP to the point just before destructors are to be called.

Eclipse [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531249/can-i-force-return-from-a-void-method-in-the-eclipse-debugger) such a feature for Java.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, E&E takes more time to compile than killing and restarting my project.

Comment: In the debugger, there's Set Next Statement command (right-click on any line, it's in the menu), which in effect jumps unconditionally to that line. So you can jump to a `return` statement, or to the closing brace.